# How can I use a .NET ConcurrentDictionary's AddOrUpdate with my custom POCO?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrentdictionary

I'm not sure how to write the `func` part of a `ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate` method, which is to check if the `UpdatedOn` property is greater than or equals to an existing key/value.

Given the following POCO, how can I use a .NET `ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate` to update an item in the dictionary (if it exists) when the new item has a DateTime value that is *GREATER THAN* the existing one ... else it just adds it.

*(pseduo code)*

```
var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Foo>();

public class Foo
{
    string Id;
    string Name;
    string Whatever;
    DateTime UpdatedOn;
}
```

I've been [looking at the 2nd overloaded method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378665%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`AddOrUpdate(TKey, TValue, Func<TKey, TValue, TValue>)`) and I'm just not sure how to do the `Func` part of the method.

Comment: What is the key and value your using with the `ConcurrentDictionay`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function parameter in question is expected to take in the key and the already existing value for that key and to return a value that should be kept in the dictionary for that very key.

So if you want to update a existing value, just create a function that updates the value and returns it instead of a new one.

---

Here's a complete example:

```
var d = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Foo>();

// an example value
var original_value = new Foo {UpdatedOn = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1)};
d.TryAdd("0", original_value);

var newValue = new Foo {UpdatedOn = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)};

// try to add the newValue with the same key
d.AddOrUpdate("0", 
              newValue,  
              (key, old_value) => {

                // if the DateTime value is greater,
                // then update the existing value
                if (newValue.UpdatedOn > old_value.UpdatedOn)
                    old_value.UpdatedOn = newValue.UpdatedOn;

                // return old_value, since it should be updated
                // instead of being replaced
                return old_value;
            });
```

`d` will now only contain the original element with `UpdatedOn` updated to 2000-1-1.